# Apache-tomcat stops at regular intervals

Tags: tomcat, crontab

I need to start tomcat every morning. One thing I suspect is there is a crontab written to clear the Catalina.out at Midnight, does it lead to stopping of tomcat by any means?

echo '' > /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/logs/catalina.out

Comment: Any failure messages ?

Comment: There is no failure message, yesterday I removed this echo '' > /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/logs/catalina.out from crontab again today morning also the site stopped working, I do a tomcat restart now works

Comment: I am looking for a permanent solution for this, now i working any issue with postgres

Comment: can you post logs from `catalina.out` ?